# What is the cardinality of the set of mathematical structures?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, cardinals

In mathematical logic, there is a set $X$ that contains all mathematical structures given a certain symbol set $S$.

E.g. lets say $S=(•,R)$ (a binary operator and a binary relation)
Let an $S$ structure $\mathfrak A$ be a tuple $(A, •,R)$ such that the two symbols have a corresponding relation that is defkned on $A$.

**What is the cardinality of $\{\mathfrak A|\mathfrak A \text{ is an $S$ structure} \}$?**

My suspicion is that it is huge. Perhaps it doesn't have a cardinality? My suspicion is: for any cardinality, we can construct another set of S structures whose domains have that cardinality, so that the set of such structures must have a cardinality greater than it. Hence the set of all such structures has an "unbounded cardinality"? (???!)

Comment: I'm not into logic/set theory by any means, but doesn't every set have a cardinality? I thought cardinality was an equivalence relation on the class of all sets. Thus if $\{\mathfrak A|\mathfrak A \text{ is an $S$ structure} \}$ is a set, it has a cardinality. How do you construct this $X$? Or is this somehow given? Is it really a set?

Comment: @Mathematician42, hmm maybe it is not a set.

Comment: I guess it can't be a set. Again I'm not into set theory nor do I properly understand the definitions involved. A set can never be an element of itself, can you somehow turn the collection $\{\mathfrak A|\mathfrak A \text{ is an $S$ structure} \}$ into an $S$ structure? If yes, then you proved it's not a set.

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for the definition of a class. For example the collection of all set is, of course, not a set. Its a proper class. The collection of all vector spaces is not a set, but a class. Same for groups and many other kinds of mathematical structures. Thats why, in category theory they say, that a category is a class, such that ... Classes are in many ways like sets, but they don't have a cardinality.

Comment: This boils down to the problem that the collection of all cardinal numbers is not a set. There are too many of them. Its a basic example of a proper class. You cannot ask: How many cardinals are there?

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus: Indeed, this much I understand. Do you know specific ways of showing that $\{\mathfrak A|\mathfrak A \text{ is an $S$ structure} \}$ is can't be a set? I gave one above, but as I said, I'm not really into this stuff, so my tool-bag is pretty small.

Comment: I can't because I don't fully understand what you mean by an $S$-structure. For vector spaces for example, the reason is, that the free vector space functor defines a vector space on any set. Therefore there are at least as much vector spaces as there are sets.

Comment: A formal definition of structure is needed.

Comment: @William: While I agree, in principle, how would that make any difference? Do you know of a definition for a mathematical structure that would not give the same result (the class of structures is a proper class)? The only thing I can think of would be "equivalence classes under isomorpshism" which then a structure is not even a set, and that would betray a lot of the foundationalism basis in set theory for this whole thing. And even then, one can use Scott's trick to make structures into sets again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct term is "a proper class", which means that this collection is not a set.

And while we can certainly talk about proper classes and to some extent treat them as sets for some rudimentary things (e.g. intersections, unions, products), these are not sets. And one thing that proper classes do not have is cardinality.<sup>1</sup>

Your idea is correct, but your argument is a bit lacking. Indeed, fixing a language, we can find arbitrarily large structure for that language, which implies that this is a proper class. But there is no "direct connection" between the cardinality of the collection of structure, and the cardinality of a new structure. If $X$ is a countable set, then $X\cup\{X\}$ is also a countable set.

The correct approach, however, would be to argue that if $X$ is a set of $S$-structures, then there is some cardinal $\kappa$ such that no member of $X$ has size $\kappa$. Therefore taking any $S$-structure of size $\kappa$, it will not be in $X$. So no *set* can exhaust all the $S$-structures.

---

**Footnotes.**

1. It is actually possible to define cardinality for proper classes, by talking about the existence of bijections between the classes. But this requires better grasp of axiomatic set theory, and understanding what does it mean for objects to live in the meta-theory and how set theory interacts with its meta-theory. So let's just agree that for now, proper classes do not have cardinality.

Comment: Asaf, can you at least give a reference for the "cardinality of classes" statement? Sounds realy interesting...

Comment: Mark, I don't know if you can find an actual reference. But essentially if a class is just "a definable collection", then you can postulate the existence of class-bijections between two definable collections as well. For example, Global Choice would be a definable bijection between $V$ and $\rm Ord$, which will then also imply that *every* proper class has also a definable bijection with the class of ordinals. So the failure of Global Choice is saying "there are several sizes of proper classes"; and without choice things can be even more complicated.

Comment: Usually these things are formulated in a class-set theory like NBG or KM, which then makes it easier to talk about such cases. But to some extent this fits into the framework of ZF(C) as well, with the usual caveats that quantifying over proper classes is not possible in the theory. (This is why I mentioned the meta-theory connection...)